# Estimate scaled up rate of gas phase reaction

Tags: catalysis, gas-phase-chemistry, rate-equation

I have measured the conversion rate of a particulate-catalyzed gas phase reaction in a reactor. That is, I have a graph of how fast $\pu{1 mol}$ of catalyst converts $\pu{1 mol}$ of reactant into $\pu{1 mol}$ of product at STP. (It’s obviously not linear, assume that I have measured it over time enough that I have a very good time-product concentration graph.) I want to estimate just scaling this to a much larger space.

Say my reactor is $\pu{10 cm^3}$ and I want to scale to, say, $\pu{10 m^3}$ assuming that same concentrations of reactants and catalyst and STP).

Is it as simple as multiplying by the volume ratio?

My probably wrong intuition is that in scaling the average travel distance between reactions and (relatedly) the rate of rebound from the walls, which gives you the pressure, scales differently, akin to the way that weight does not scale with surface area.

I’m also slightly worried that a catalyzed reaction has a different non-obvious answer. I’m sure that this has a standard answer (and it’s probably just that it scales by volume ratio), but I’m checking my intuition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I general, you can't just expect that process like that would be scaleable in any simple way, afaik.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: 1 mole is like 1 kilogram (unit names) // 1 mol is like 1 kg (unit symbols). //  For options of formatting of the posted plain text, see as inspiration [SE - help - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: MAny things in chemical reactions do not scale with larger volumes or mass, so this isn't easy. For example, heat transfer. volume of stuff in a reactor scales with the cube of the size, but the surface area only scales with the square of the size (so heat will be far harder to manage heat transfer depends on the surface not the volume).